# in swift, wrong time is displayed for a date outside daylight saving, depending on the time of call

Tags: ios, swift, dateformatter

i am currently having the following problem with relation to daylight saving.

Using the UI the user creates an entry for a specific date and time.
eg.: on 20.10 (so DST, this is the time where she is using the app) she creates an entry for 28.10 11:00 (this is outside the DST)

we create a date object like this, the format is the one used in the UI:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter.getFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM d, yyyy HH:mm"
self.startDate = dateFormatter.date(from: label.text!)!
```

no further processing is done and the date object is saved locally in realm.
printing the object shows 2020-10-28 09:00:00 +0000 which is correct, since we are in CET (GMT +2 in summer).

As long as the device's date is before 25.10 (so in DST) the date is correctly displayed throughout the app.

Now, after the DST (starting with 25.10) the app wrongly displays 28.10 10:00.
We are now in winter time which is GMT +1

it seems that swift wrongly uses the DST setting for the time when it is called, rather then the actual datetime that is being converted.

what am i doing wrong? any other technology that we used would correctly display the time, as long as the timezone is the same.

Comment: Can you show what `DateFormatter.getFormatter()` does?

Comment: it just shows the pointer value <NSDateFormatter: 0x2831f0de0>. what exactly would you want to check?

Comment: I mean, please show the code for that method.

Comment: oo sorry, i did not realise that this was done by us, i thought it was a static constructor.
it has this line, which i think is the problem:

if TimeZone.current.isDaylightSavingTime() {
            formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: TimeZone.current.secondsFromGMT())
        }

will check and get back

Comment: Yep, that is definitely the problem.

Comment: yes that was it. thanks.